# Cannot uninstall python 3.10

Tags: python

I tried to upgrade to python3.10 following

https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux

After I did this visual studio code stopped working.

I tried to remove 3.10 by

```
    sudo apt remove python3.10
```

however this did not remove /usr/bin/python3.10

I fixed the problem with visual studio code by changing the default python interpreter  (which somehow got changed to /usr/bin/python3.10

if I try to run my code from inside studo code (with /usr/bin/python3.10 as the interpreter)  I get a lot of error messages and my machine hangs up so I have to do a cold reboot.  If I run the code outside studio code
/usr/bin/python3.8 works fine but /usr/bin/python3.19 fails when trying to import the module english_words  (says that no such module exits)

Is there any way to upgrade to 3.10 which will not break studio code?

Comment: Create a virtual environment and install 3.10.